# Strange thing when use Ad hoc distribution

Tags: ios, core-data

I distribute my app by using Ad hoc distribution. After I download my app, and log in, then the app begin to download some data and save something with core data, but it could not be saved. Then I terminate the app and try again, it succeed. Something wrong, I think!
I tried many times and found that every first time I installed the app, the save core data action would fail, then I terminate app, tried again, it succeed. At first time it failed, could some strange message blew.

```
(com.apple.ubd) <Notice>: (com.apple.ubd) Throttling respawn: Will start in 1 seconds
```

In degug model, the strange thing would not happen.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Are you using iCloud? That's what `com.apple.ubd` usually means.

Comment: I don't use iCould, it matters?

Answer (score 1):

It could a pair of things:

- Maybe the time to execute `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` is too long when you init the App the first time and crash it.
- If you are using MagicalRecord try to find `[self setShouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch:NO];` line and set to YES in no DEBUG mode.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
My app doesn't use MagicalRecord. 
In
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
I add a root view controller to window, which contains a login view. When use login, I use a thread to check update and download update in background and go to the Home page. Then when updating finished, the strange thing happen. It seemed the core data could not be saved correctly.